# How can I prevent and optimize a bad variable name?

Tags: shell, sh

When I run the code the output is `./fib.sh: 43: read: 6: bad variable name`. What does it mean and how do I fix it?

```
case $# in 
0)
echo "plz insert 3 integer number \n" && read a b n;;
1)a=$1 && echo "plz insert 2 integer number\n " && read b n ;;
2) a=$1 b=$2 && echo "plz insert 1 intger number \n" && read n ;;
3)a=$1 b=$2 n=$3 ;;
*)echo "The number of arguments is more than 3\n" && exit 1 ;;
esac
echo " a=$a  b=$b  n=$n\n"
while true  ; do
if [ $n -eq 0 ] ;then 
echo $a
elif [ $n -eq 1 ];then 
echo $b
elif [ $n -ge 2 ] ; then 
printf "%s ""$a"
printf "%s ""$b"
count=1
c=`expr $n - 1`
 while [ $count -le $c ] ; do
 printf "%s ""$answer"
answer=`expr $a + $b`
a=$b
b=$answer
count=`expr $count + 1`
done
echo "\nDo you want to try another n (yes/no):\n"
read s  
    case $s in
        yes) echo"\nenter new value of n \n" && read $n && continue ;;
        no) echo "Thank you" && exit 1 ;;
    esac
fi
done
```

Comment: Which is line 43, please?

Comment: Please don't tag with unrelated languages. /// There aren't 43 lines in that code. Don't claim that code you posted produced output it couldn't possibly have produced. Don't post code you didn't run. Don't post code with lots of irrelevant detail. Post a *minimal*, runnable demonstration of the problem, which include providing the necessary inputs to replicate the problem

Comment: What's the value of `$n` when you do `read $n`? Should that be `read n`?

Comment: Tip: You'd do well to indent your code. What you posted isn't readable.

Comment: use https://shellcheck.net to improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

> `read: 6: bad variable name.`

`read $n` expands the value of the variable `n` which, in this case, is  6. So that's `read 6` trying to read into the variable 6. 6 is not a valid variable name in shell.

From context, you want to read into n which is `read n`.

```
yes) echo"\nenter new value of n \n" && read n && continue ;;
```

Comment: it's not working! when I  do that he didn't ask for a new value!

Comment: @Areej Do you mean the error is gone and something else isn't working?

Comment: the problem is an infinite loop